# How to handle file uploads in WHMCS php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have trouble uploading a file in WHMCS.

In their API documentation http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Open_Ticket file upload is not allowed.

How can I handle these file uploads?

Comment: So you want to do something that is explicitly not provided and not intended to be provided by the tool you are using? Good luck with that. BTW If you are going to ask for help with a tool then typing the name of the tool correctly is a basic first step that you neglected to take care to get right.

Answer (score 1):

The whmcs open_ticket api does not allow attachments, the only way is messing with the whmcs ticket tables but i do not recommend it at all. A workaround is to send an email and it will be automatically imported by whmcs instead of using the api.

Answer (score 0):

update your whmcs
It works for +7.10 version